# Select table cells with id

Tags: jquery

Help, if not difficult. I have a select and a table. I need to show table cells with a specific id (or class), and hide the rest of the cells. I need to do this on jQuery.

```
<select id="sel">
  <option value = "cat1">Category1</option>
  <option value = "cat2">Category2</option>
</select>
    <table>
    <tr id="my1">
        <td>Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="my2">
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="my1">
        <td>Value 1-1</td>
        <td>Value 1-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="my2">
        <td>Value 2-2</td>
        <td>Value 2-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="my1">
        <td>Value 2-1</td>
        <td>Value 2-1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code is not valid, ids have to be unique. You can change to classes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned as comment, your code isn't valid as id attributes have to be unique. You can change to classes instead. If you change that, you can show the rows based on the selected value like that:

```js
$("#sel").change(function() {
  selected = $(this).val();
  number = selected.substr(3);
  $("tr").hide();
  $("tr[class='my" + number + "']").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
  <option value = "cat1">Category1</option>
  <option value = "cat2">Category2</option>
</select>
    <table>
    <tr class="my1">
        <td>Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="my2">
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="my1">
        <td>Value 1-1</td>
        <td>Value 1-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="my2">
        <td>Value 2-2</td>
        <td>Value 2-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="my1">
        <td>Value 2-1</td>
        <td>Value 2-1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Update: As it's necessary to show all rows again, I add "Select" as new option to the select and show all rows when "Select" is selected:

```js
$("#sel").change(function() {
  selected = $(this).val();
  if (selected != 0) {
    number = selected.substr(3);
    $("tr").hide();
    $("tr[class='my" + number + "']").show();
  } else {
    $("tr").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value = "cat1">Category1</option>
  <option value = "cat2">Category2</option>
</select>
    <table>
    <tr class="my1">
        <td>Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="my2">
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="my1">
        <td>Value 1-1</td>
        <td>Value 1-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="my2">
        <td>Value 2-2</td>
        <td>Value 2-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="my1">
        <td>Value 2-1</td>
        <td>Value 2-1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And how to show all the cells of the table again? If not difficult.

Comment: @Ivan It's not difficult, it's just the question what should happen on your page to show all the cells again. I suggest to add the option "Select" in the select dropdown, and if "Select" is selected, all table rows are shown again. Should I just adjust my answer for this or do you have a different approach for that requirement? It would be like in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0gn87zLs/

Comment: Thank you so much! While I tried, you already wrote the code!

Comment: @Ivan Glad I was able to help :) I just add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$('table tr').css('display','none');

$('table tr[id="my1"]').css('display','block');

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Rajesh! Based on your example, I tried writing code. It works, but it doesn’t look very good. Of course, @matthias_h code is much better.

```
$('select').change(function() {
        $('table tr').css('display', 'none');
        var sl = $('#sel :selected').val();
        if (sl == 'cat1') {   
            $('table tr[id="my1"]').css('display', 'block');
        } else if (sl == 'cat2') {       
            $('table tr[id="my2"]').css('display', 'block');
        } else if (sl == 'cat0') {
            $('table tr').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
```